# How can I accept Bitcoin donations on my blog or site?

Tags: payment, ecommerce, donation

If I sell things, there are many services that allow me to accept bitcoins as payment.  But for those who simply want to accept bitcoins on their blog or other site ... as donations.

A simple bitcoin address can be listed but what other options are available, such as an icon that can be clicked on, like what Flattr offers, perhaps?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Although bloggers could turn to an external service to manage this for them, it might be more beneficial to simply offer a simple QR code with a description alongside. This would mean that all of the income from the BTCs would go direct to the blogger.

My personal blog has [an article describing in detail how to do this](http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2012/01/09/how-to-accept-bitcoins-on-your-blog-with-no-code/). I'm not trying to plug anything honestly, just sharing knowledge.

This can be imaged with a Bitcoin wallet, or dragged like a Bitcoin swatch onto the Multibit client. A simple click will trigger a protocol handler within the browser (if installed) that would activate an wallet plugin.

Comment: qr codes and bitcoin URIs are cute and all... but you're on a computer... reading a blog... so all you really need is a bitcoin address that you can copy and paste into your client. :)

Comment: Why copy and paste (big faff on an iPad) when you can just click? What if you are reading a blog off a friend's phone and think, "You know, I'd like to support that? I'll just use that QR code to activate my mobile phone's Bitcoin wallet..."

Comment: well you see, you're talking to someone who doesn't have a fancy phone or an ipad :) but i suppose if you're using devices that make it hard to copy and paste, this would make a lot more sense. ;)

Comment: When you click on a Bitcoin URI using Multibit it copies not just the address but also the label and amount. It also adds the new address + label into your list of previous addresses. It also starts up Multibit if it is not running. That is all done with a single click in the browser.

Comment: While simple, this is just a simple link. A modal would focus the user on the donation (see the [Coinbase example](https://www.coinbase.com/docs/merchant_tools/payment_buttons)), and a few other features from open-source project [Cointipper](https://github.com/jeremymouton/cointipper/issues) make the experience more modern

Answer (score 5):

And Blockchain.info has added Facebook "pay a friend" feature.

- http://www.Blockchain.info

Another method -- for requesting funds is:

- http://www.bitcoinchipin.com

Another thread on this topic:

- http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/v51nz/newb_here_i_have_a_couple_of_websites_and_want_to/

Comment: Hey Stephen, in this last edit bit-pay.com was removed as a dead link. Was that the same service today found at bitpay.com?

Answer (score 3):

More methods:

- http://leo.bogert.de/2012/02/22/simple-bitcoin-donate-button
- http://ecdsa.org:8080/widgets
- http://bitcoinate.org

Comment: The first two links are dead, and the last just displays a JavaScript prompt with the Bitcoin address.

Comment: Please, change dead links to http://wayback.archive.org/web/20130621033546/http://leo.bogert.de/2012/02/22/simple-bitcoin-donate-button/ and http://wayback.archive.org/web/20111210172451/http://ecdsa.org:8080/widgets . I can not offer my editing due to technical limitations. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the easiest way (if you do not care about staying anonymous, which you probably don't wont in the case of donations anyway), is to just display a Bitcoin receiving address with a nice icon next to it (and maybe link it to a page with instructions, QR codes and stuff).

As for icons, there is a collection at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Promotional_graphics, be sure to also follow the links at the bottom.

> > There is also the possibility that Favicons could be used as a shorthand in browse address