# Support sending bitcoins using webpage URL?

Tags: address, websites, donation

Are there any Bitcoin clients or services that support sending bitcoins to a HTTP(S) URL instead of having to enter a Bitcoin address directly? (e.g. [for donations](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2161/4975))

---

Webmasters could include their Bitcoin address in a `link` element in each page (same for the whole site or different for each page, e.g. to account which page generated which donation):

```
<link rel="payment" href="bitcoin:…" title="Donate bitcoins, if my article was of help to you">
```

The `href` attribute should contain the Bitcoin address, using the [`bitcoin` URI scheme](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4987/4975).

The `rel` attribute should have the value [`payment`](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-payment). It’s defined as:

> RelPayment is a microformat for making exchanges of support (be it financial or otherwise) possible. By adding rel="payment" to a hyperlink a page indicates that the destination of that hyperlink provides a way to show or give support for the current page. For example **to give financial support to the owner of the current page**.

The (optional) `title` attribute could contain a small note, e.g. what the donations are used for, or who exactly would be the receiver etc.

---

Tools (Bitcoin clients/services, browser add-ons etc.) could extract the Bitcoin address by looking for a link with the link type `payment` whose URI uses the scheme `bitcoin`.
If one enters a webpage URL that hasn’t linked a Bitcoin address, the tool should throw an error. For security reasons probably only `link` elements should be parsed (instead of `a`/`area`), otherwise e.g. commentators could include their own Bitcoin addresses.

Comment: These things should probably be implemented by browsers, not by clients.

Comment: You could create a browser extension yourself that allows you to donate to the current page (when it supports it).

Comment: @e-sushi: It’s not a duplicate. A Bitcoin URI scheme is for representing a Bitcoin address as URI, while this question is about using HTTP URIs to send Bitcoin (which could *make use* of a Bitcoin URI specified on the HTML page).

Comment: @unor Woops, my bad… didn’t notice that what you’ve asked about was looking for something going the other way around. Removed my “dupe” comment accordingly.

Comment: @asterisk: My reply to e-sushi’s comment above is about the same question: I don’t think it’s a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

The client [Electrum](http://electrum.org/) seems to support something like that (using a different method): [Aliases](http://electrum.org/bitcoin_URIs.html):

> Aliases may be server names (e.g. `ecdsa.org`) or email-like addresses (e.g. `john.doe@ecdsa.org`)
> The corresponding Bitcoin address is retrieved by the client, using a descriptor located at a canonical url.
>
> Aliases may be entered in the Electrum client, or used in Bitcoin URIs […]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I think this feature is going to be awesome; I guess its already included in the HTML5 specs:
https://html5.org/r/7850

If this worked similar to "mailto:" across all browsers & OSes, it could become ridiculously easy to accept payments through your website, maybe BitPay wouldn't be needed as long as native clients could pick up the slack & do currency conversion etc. Right now the user needs to exit your page and pull up their wallet to make a payment, which is a huge barrier.

Answer (score -2):

Armory already supports donating with a syntax like this.  The syntax is as follows:

```
bitcoin:1ArmoryXcfq7TnCSuZa9fQjRYwJ4bkRKfv?amount=1.0&label=Armory%20Developers&message=Donation%20to%20Armory
```

See https://bitcoinarmory.com/ for the reference of where I got this from, it's at the bottom of the page before the QR code.

That's just an http link where it is using bitcoin: as a prefix similar to how email links are setup, it has the bitcoin amount, the label, and the the address all pretty clearly labeled here.

Comment: You haven't addressed the question, you've just re-stated http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4987/bitcoin-url-scheme as already included and linked to in the question.

Comment: OP is looking for  services that support sending bitcoins to a HTTP(S) URL instead of having to enter a Bitcoin address directly, So, your answer is rather useless.